# Implicit deref coercion not working with impl Trait

Tags: rust, traits, coercion

Consider the following setup.

```rust
pub trait Draw {
    fn draw(&self) {}
}

pub struct Square;
impl Draw for Square {}

fn draw_it(v: &dyn Draw) {}

fn main() {
    let bs: Box<dyn Draw> = Box::new(Square {});
    
    // 1.
    draw_it(bs.deref());  // OK
    draw_it(&*bs);        // OK

    // 2.
    draw_it(&bs); // FAILS
}
```

Why does `1.` work just fine, but `2.` doesn't? I would have expected the implicit deref coercion rule to make `2.` be equivalent to `1.`.

That is, `<Box<dyn Draw> as Deref>::deref(&bs)` returns a value of type `&dyn Draw`, and this is what `draw_it()` expects as an argument, so why isn't the compiler finding the coercion by applying the implicit deref coercion rule?

Comment: To quote one of the answers in the suggested dupe: *"deref coercion doesn't apply to a cast to a trait object type"*